# AndroidManifest.xml file missing error while running Maven Android project

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, maven

I am missing the AndroidManifest.xml file while executing my Maven Android Application project in Eclipse. But the AndroidManifest.xml is present in my project, and pom.xml is successfully compiled and built.

Project Directory structure:

> /MavenTestProject/gen
>
> /MavenTestProject/src/main/java
>
> com.ap.amrit.MavenTestProject
>
> /MavenTestProject/src/main/java/
>
> - com/ap/amrit/MavenTestProject/
>
>   -HelloAndroidActivity.java
>
> /MavenTestProject/src/test/java
>
> /MavenTestProject/assets
>
> /MavenTestProject/bin
>
> /MavenTestProject/res
>
> /MavenTestProject/src
>
> /MavenTestProject/target
>
> /MavenTestProject/AndroidManifest.xml
>
> /MavenTestProject/pom.xml
>
> /MavenTestProject/project.properties

Contents in pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ap.amrit</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenTestProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>MavenTestProject</name>

<properties>
    <platform.version></platform.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>


        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javac.exe
                </executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path>E:\utils\AndroidSDK</path>
                    <platform>17</platform>
                </sdk>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>

                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

The pom.xml file is successfully built, but while running project as Android Application project, it is giving "Error: as your project contains errors, please fix them before running."  In the problems section, it's showing that the AndroidManifest.xml file is missing.

Could anyone help me in sorting out this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haha..eclipse sometimes tries to fools user.., you are getting AndroidManifest.xml missing error because it is not present in you project's bin folder. Please try to clean & build your project again, if required try to refresh project and crosscheck if Androidmanifest.xml is present in your bin folder. Have fun..!! Enjoy!!